# custom control with Collection: the Collection Editor appears but immediate dissappears again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom control (that should show up in the toolbox) that must have a collection of another class.
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095899/how-to-use-an-items-collection-editor-on-a-custom-usercontrol-net-4-winforms) question as my guideline.
But I hit the following problem.

When I drop the control on a form, and click on the 3dotted button on the dsTables property, I can see the `Collection Editor Form` appearing, but also disappearing again very quickly.

So I must be forgetting something.

This is my code full code

```
public partial class gttDataSet : DataSet
{
    private dsTables _dsTables = new dsTables();

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor, System.Design", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public dsTables gttTables
    {
        get { return _dsTables; }
        set { _dsTables = value; }
    }
}

public class dsTables : BaseCollection
{
    // See `EDIT 2:` at the bottom of the question
    public object[] Items()
    {
        object[] test = List.ToArray();
        return test;
    }

    // See `EDIT 1:` at the bottom of the question
    public dsTable Item(int index)
    {
        return (dsTable)List[index];
    }

    public dsTable Add()
    {
        dsTable Result = new dsTable();
        this.List.Add(Result);
        return Result;
    }

    public void Remove(dsTable table)
    {
        List.Remove(table);
    }

    public int IndexOf(dsTable table)
    {
        return List.IndexOf(table);
    }

    public bool Contains(dsTable table)
    {
        return List.Contains(table);
    }
}

public class dsTable
{
    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string SelectText { get; set; }

    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string SelectTextForUpdate { get; set; }

    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string DesignWhereText { get; set; }

    [Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    string UserWhereText { get; set; }

    bool IsStoredProcedure { get; set; }

    bool RetrieveColumns { get;  }
}
```

Why does the `Collection Editor Form` disappears immediate after showing up ?

**EDIT 1:**
added the property Item to the Collection class dsTables because on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor?view=net-5.0#examples) site they say its is needed for collection editors

**EDIT 2:**
Added `public object[] Items()` because several websites tell me its needed for the Collection Editor to determine the type of object to handle.
Unfortunate it does not fixes my problem

**EDIT 3:**
Tried it with Items as a property in stead of a method. But also that did not fixed the problem.

```
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            object[] test = List.ToArray();
            return test;
        }

        set 
        {
            _dsTables.Clear();
            foreach (object item in value)
            {
                _dsTables.Add((dsTable)item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem, it turns out I was using the wrong type to inherit from

so

```
public class dsTables : BaseCollection
```

must be

```
public class dsTables : CollectionBase
```

Now the `Collection Editor Windows` shows up and stays up.